# On the website headers design

Tags: support, design

As a loving user of `TeX-based` typesetting systems, being also interested in the integration of high-quality graphic content in technical and scientific documentation, I resort daily to the facilities provided by `PSTricks` and `TikZ`.

I have been wondering for quite a while if the beautiful headers in this website have been laid out using those packages and, if so, if the source code is available or if some hints could be provided on how the engraving-like look has been achieved.

I know that this can be done with GUI-based vector graphics software (Inkscape, Adobe Illustrator and those of their ilk), but I want to do all my graphic work embedded in the programming `TeX` + `PostScript` joint system.

My congratulations and gratitude for the website layout, contents and activity.

Comment: And I wonder who is the creator, too!

Comment: Here's a very detailed account of the design process: [Site design ideas](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/638/2693).

Comment: Thanks for the link, which I have followed. Nonetheless, my main point concerned the letter press effect in the headers and it seems to me there are no tips on how it has been done. My system has the corresponding Hoefler typeface, but this effect is not in the typeface itself.

Comment: My guess would be that Jin did it in Photoshop or something similar.

Comment: If you want to know how to create the effect in TeX, why not ask on the main site?

Comment: Since this was about the website layout I thought it would be more appropriate asking about it in here. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Marcos: Well, the answer to the website layout is that it wasn't done in TeX. So “how to do that in TeX” is an entirely independent question.

Comment: Posting as a comment since this doesn't answer your question, more of a FYI. The header {TeX} logo was done in Photoshop, so is its letter pressed effect. The typeface is [Hoefler Text](http://www.typography.com/fonts/font_overview.php?productLineID=100010)

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. My congratulations for the beautiful design.